# Best way to wrap ember-data models with their controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a custom view with a render function that needs to do some calculations. Since I've put all my display logic and properties that the app does not need to save or get on  to the server in an ObjectController I need to manually "wrap" my model with the controller to get some computed properties. It works, but isn't there a better/cleaner way? So current code in the view is:

```
...
currentPage = pages.filterBy('nr', pageNb).get('firstObject')
currentPageCntl = @cntl.get('controllers.page').set('model',currentPage)
currentPageDimensions = currentPageCntl.get('dimensions')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you have logic and data that you don't want to include in your model, even though they belong together in certain places. I'm actually working on an issue very similar to this right now. I don't know if this is the best way to do things, but the way I've been doing it is to wrap the Ember-Data model is an object that more closely represents the model that you want. For instance, here's what that might look like for you:

```
App.Page = DS.Model.extend

App.PageWrapper = Ember.Object.extend
    page: null

    dimensions: () -> 
        # ...
    .property('page')
```

So for your application, don't treat the `page` like your model, treat the `pageWrapper` as your model. So change your `currentPage` to:

```
currentPage = App.PageWrapper.create
    page: pages.filterBy('nr', pageNb).get('firstObject')
```

This way, you can add whatever logic/models you want to the wrapper class, but still keep it distinct from your page. I might be able to help you come up with something more Ember-like if you gave me some more info, but this is a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: I know computed properties aren't saved on the server. And I can move dimension to the model, but then I have to move a whole lot of other stuff( bindings, other computed properties,...) to the model since the dimension property depends on them and that doesn't look very clean to me.

Comment: OK, that makes much more sense. Let me revise my answer.

Comment: That's close to what I meant. But aren't you just imitating an ObjectController. I think this makes things even more complicated. Before, if could make currentPage hold the controller and do currentPage.get('dimensions') and currentPage.get('id') (model's property). So I definitely think the ObjectController is what I want, I just thought it would be nice (and handy) if it was possible, in this case, for `pages.filterBy('nr', pageNb).get('firstObject')` to return my objectcontroller that wraps my model. But thx for your insights.

Comment: Well, if you switch to using an `ArrayController` for your page models, it can automatically wrap items in an array for you (as detailed [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/)). Don't know if that's a possibility though.